# Express API enpoint localhost:3000/xxx is not working, but localhost:3000/ is

Tags: node.js, express, rest

I wanted to write an API with *express*, but I am stuck right at the beginning.
When I am acessing `localhost:3000` it seams to work, but as soon as I write `localhost:3000/hello` a 404 Error occours (*Cannot GET /hello*).

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to application." });
});

app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to hello." });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: If you're not use nodemon, its mean your server is not auto restart. Then you have to manually restart your backend after you add new router. And it will working fine.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code.